# Object Literal 'this' to reference Object in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, this

I'm working on a script that gives me the error saying *Object doesn't support this property or method*. I'm pretty sure IE8 refers to `this` as the Window Object.

```
var self = {
  method1: function () {

  },
  method2: function () {
    this.method1();
  }
};
```

Is there anyway to overcome this error of 'this' when referring to the Object's self? I've seen posts about `.call(this)` but not sure if this is relevant here. Thanks!

I'm calling the function like so:

```
var Module = (function () {
  var self = {
    method1: function () {

    },
    method2: function () {
      this.method1();
    }
  };
  return self;
})();

// init
Module.method2();
```

Comment: How are you calling `method2`?

Comment: I'm returning it via return self; then calling Module.method1() elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: @Jon I've updated the above with the method.

Comment: `self.method2()` in the first example would work, and `Module.method2()` would also work. In general, when you do `foo.bar()` then inside `bar` `this` will be equal to `foo`. Therefore these examples should run just fine. Contrast this with `var f = foo.bar; f();`, when `this` would be the global object inside the body of `bar`.

Comment: @Jon, Hmmm, it works when I change 'this' to 'self'. self.method1() inside the self object. I'm passing in (window, document) into the IIFE too, do you think that would affect the 'this'?

Comment: If you change `this` to `self` you sidestep the problem; perhaps that would be a good idea, depends on the context. Passing args to the IIFE should not affect anything.

Comment: seems like you have another variable with the name `self` ?

Comment: @Jon, @Jayantha - I've added `alert(this)` inside the function and in IE8 it alerts [object Window].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return the object form your function,

```
var Module = (function () {
  return  {
    method1: function () {

    },
    method2: function () {
      this.method1();
    }
  };
})();


 Module.method2();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NL99N/2/

yes you can call a function like this as well,

```
self.method2.call(self);
```